# Ignore/Exclude folder from jshint gulp.js

Tags: javascript, gulp, web-frontend, build-system

I am trying to exclude the vendor folder in gulp. I have read a few tutorials and howto's none of them are working i've tried this

```
js = {
    in: source + 'js/**/*', '!js/vendor/**/*.js'
    out: dest + 'js/',
    filename: 'main.js'
},
```

and something to the effect of

```
([in: source + 'js/**/*', '!js/vendor/**/*.js')
```

the second option completely ignores the js all together. Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you in advance.

Comment: Those are both invalid syntax.

Comment: Yea I figured when they didn't work but those were the only examples that I could find. On both Google and YouTube. Can you help me out? do you need to see my full gulpfile?

Comment: You need to set the `in` property to an array of two strings.

Comment: That worked perfect. Took me a minute to figure it out first few attempts crashed but eh. Im new to SO how do I check this or give you credit for helping me come up with the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gulp is normal Javascript; you need to write a regular object with an `in` property that holds an array of two strings.